# Getting error while executing DHCP power shell command

Tags: powershell, dhcp

I need to read vendor specification data from DHCP server options.

I have connected an android mobile to my PC, enabled the tethering and exposed the DHCP server IP: 192.168.42.129 as shown in the image.
[image]

As per MSDN site this is the syntax:

```
(Get-DhcpServerv4OptionValue -ComputerName "dhcpserver.contoso.com")
```

for getting DHCP options through power shell. I tried the same but get the error.
Did I miss anything?

Comment: You need to install the DHCP Server Management Tools [RSAT](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520) feature to use the relevant module on your PC

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen i have installed. am getting other ERROR(Get-DhcpServerv4OptionValue : Failed to get version of the DHCP server 192.168.42.129.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-DhcpServerv4OptionValue -ComputerName "192.168.42.129"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (192.168.42.129:root/Microsoft/...erv4OptionValue) [Get-DhcpServerv4Option
   Value], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WIN32 1722,Get-DhcpServerv4OptionValue)now:

Comment: After installing RSAT and enabling the DHCP tools feature (and possibly rebooting), the commands should be recognized - if not, try explicitly importing the module: `Import-Module dhcpserver`

Comment: Error `1722` means the RPC endpoint on the remote machine didn't respond - is WinRM configured on the target server? Does all firewalls between the two machines permit traffic from your machine to tcp/5985 on the target?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  In windows 10 machine, i have turn off firewall, i am not sure how to permit from target machine(android mobile). does WinRM exist in android mobile?, if yes, how can we configure. actually requirement is that need to read vendor specific information from dhcp options from window machine which will connect to android mobile through socket.

Comment: The `dhcpserver` module _only works with Windows DHCP Servers_ - if you're trying to _manage_ a DHCP server/daemon running on your android device, these cmdlets won't be able to help you